# Swiffy converted Flash texts appear blurry

Tags: flash, blurry, google-swiffy

I am converting SWF file into HMTL files using Swiffy converter. These SWF files contain texts, tables and interactions (like click events and showing popups). The converted HTML content looks fuzzy and blurry. Crispness gone from the texts and vectors shapes. Edges of shapes and texts appear blurred. I have tried different text settings such as Bitmap text (no-anti alias), anti-alias for animation and anti-alias for readability, but all of these give same blurry output. Help is needed to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in this process is that the text in flash is vector based and hard to compete with.

some things to try:
* make sure the SWF quality is at maximum
* check the fonts that are being used as some simply don't rasterise very well
* are you scaling the conversion?
* the text is being converted to a bitmap font so try to get the import and export sizes as close as possible
* it's worth checking the output in various browsers as this can help to point to the underlying issue
* a pain in the ass, but you could edit the converted bitmaps directly post Swiffy conversion

Rich

Comment: I am really thankful to you for this suggestion. I didn't scale that. In fact, Swiffy does not allow to scale down. Does it? I changed the dimension and instead of getting smaller, the content got trimmed. But anyway, I have found its solution. I had changed the text property to 'device font' and letter-spacing of 0.1-0.2 (in bold texts), the output was awesome. No blurriness and no legibility issue. At last, got the quality in Swiffy conversion. Thanks again Rich for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your object is 100% scale, it's important (if you need to rescale object do it inside the "movie clip" or "graphic" object (all graphic and movie clip object inside of an another object also needs to be 100% scale)). Also some vector graphics looks better when they are only "graphic" object.

One of the solutions is: convert your text to movieclip object (100% scale) and check the "use runtime bitmap caching" in properties dialog. If text apears still blury - break it apart until it converts to shapes (though not a solution for large texts, but usualy works for single text lines).

Answer (score 0):

the object on stage must have total px values in its initial size & position (x & y)

So no decimals there. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGQ4d.png)